# Selecting previous day's data with timezone

Tags: sql, psql

I have a psql query that executes every day at midnight Pacific Standard Time.

The query should select every record of the previous day in `mytable`.

`mytable` contains a `time` column which is a `timestamp with timezone` and the timezone is the standard UTC

Both of these queries

```
select * from mytable WHERE timezone('US/Pacific', time) >= timezone('US/Pacific', now() - '24 hour')

select * from mytable WHERE timezone('US/Pacific', time) >= timezone('US/Pacific', now()) - '24 hour'
```

throw errors:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "24 hour"
LINE 1: ...' , time ) >= timezone ( 'US/Pacific' , now ( ) - '24 hour' ...
```

Would a query including the following syntax work with timezone?

```
 ... WHERE time >= TIMESTAMP 'yesterday' AND time < TIMESTAMP 'today'
```

What is the best practice in psql and how should this query be written? Any explanation would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for subtracting 24 hours is off.  It should be this:

```
timezone('US/Pacific', now() - interval '24 hour')
                                ^^^       ^^^
```

Full query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE timezone('US/Pacific', time) >= timezone('US/Pacific', now() - interval '24 hour')
```

Note that since both terms in the `WHERE` clause are being shifted to the same timezone, it should be possible to just compare them in the (default) UTC time which Postgres stores internally:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE time >= now() - interval '24 hour';
```

Comment: Thank you.  In PSQL, would it be better practice to use EXTRACT date where the date is equal to yesterday, or is this convention too slow?

Comment: @the_darkside Actually, since both terms of your `WHERE` clause are being shifted to the same timezone, I don't even see the point of using the `timezone` function.